# Unable to add indices while migrating room database

Tags: java, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I am migrating room database version from 1 to version 2. While migrating I have added Indices in migration code but it's not working.

Below is the code:

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {

             database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE student (" +
                    "student_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ," +
                    "student_name TEXT," +
                    "student_roll_no TEXT," +
                    "department_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES department(dept_id)" +
                    ")");
            database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX `index_student_department_id` ON `student` (`department_id`)");


        }
    };
```

This results in :-

```
Expected indices=[Index{name='index_student_department_id', unique=false, columns=[department_id]}]
Result Found:indices=null
```

Comment: Did you found a solution? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make entity for Student table to have indices making the index. Message saying expected but **`indices`** but found nothing.

Like

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index(name="`index_student_department_id`", unique = false, value =  {"`department_id`"})})
public class Student {
    .......
}
```

or (as `unique = false` is default)

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index(name="`index_student_department_id`", value =  {"`department_id`"})})
public class Student {
    .......
}
```

Comment: Doing it same way but it still giving me error on migrating database